# Mosfet Gate Driver IC

Tags: mosfet, pwm, driver

Ok so I have burned about 10 MIC4605 [(Datasheet here )](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005853A.pdf) gate drivers this weekend. I am unsure as to how they should be PROPERLY wired.

Also have burned 8 out 10 MOSFETS [(Datasheet Here )](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/Infineon-IPD040N03LG-DS-v02_01-en-522802.pdf)

Page 1 of the datasheet shows a typical application which is interesting because the motor I am using is 140mA @12V

[image]
So I wired it just like that...Magic Smoke came out
I tried to PWM the low side mosfet of one side of the bridge while the other side had the high mosfet activated. Things blew up.

So i figured this must be some sort of circuit diagram where "things are assumed" like schottky Diodes. After some research 
I found this on Microchips own website and the funny thing is the circuit diagram looks a lot different than the datasheet.

[image: Sample circuit]

So now I have this wired up and I am down to 1 Gate driver left alive after burning 9.
This circuit seems to work. I am not using a 24V bus, My motor and my gate driver are both being fed by a 12V coming from my power supply. In the circuit above I am not using the lowside mosfet, instead I am just testing the high side mosfet and my motor's other lead goes directly to ground.

This works just fine at 12V and I am PWM'ing perfectly fine and works well, until I turn the voltage up to 16V and then my driver dies.

My only guess is that BACK emf becomes too large and kills something, but I have all the diodes in the schamtic in their rightful place..

I am PWModulating at 32Khz.

My ultimate goal is a Full Bridge Motor driver with all N-channel MOSFETS and having atleast 2 Mosfets in parallel for each high side and low side, but i cant even get past one mosfet at a conservative voltage.

Comment: Are you using the -1 version or the -2 version of MIC4605?

Comment: Ive managed to burn up both,  i Had 10 of the 1 version and 4 of the 2 versions

Comment: the last working circuit I have has the 1 version

Comment: How are you controlling the inputs? Is there a "minimum 50ns delay between both inputs" as "HI and
LI inputs must not rise at the same time"

Comment: Well, one input for testing purposes is always LOW (Mosfet OFF) while the other is getting PWM. SO i am not driving them in a complimentary manner as of yet but the IC takes care of dead time

Comment: Hmm. I'm guessing you've double checked the wiring, and the high side MOSFETs have drain to VDD, and source to HO.

Comment: The irony (and perhaps coincidence) in this is that your last name is "Fairchild" lol. I'm assuming the way you hooked up your circuit is exactly what the schematic shows? After burning through 8 chips, I'm assuming that something in your schematic is wrong. It wouldn't make sense to go through 8 ICs and wire it improperly all of those times.

Comment: Also, have you tried with something like a 1K resistor as a load instead of the motor? Just to rule out it being some form of EMF or over current issue.

Comment: Well high  MOSFET Source goes to HS, HO goes to gate. Could be a breadboard issue, I think I am going to opt for a gate driver with a DIP version for protyping and then use the SMD version for PCB. Right now I am using these SOIC8 breakout pcb with pins. but its just weird that all works fine till i up the voltage

Comment: I think I will do that!! Put a dummy load and make sure its not the back emf! thanks for the tip.

Comment: Cross-conduction due to poor dead-band design is chief failure mode. Inductance delays included

Comment: @TomCarpenter I just tried, and I even pushed the IC to 20Vdd with a  1K load and It worked flawless. HAS to be the dam back EMF!!!

Comment: Back EMF must be returned to Voltage if your source can sink as well otherwise there can be a problem . Make sure the full bridge ESR is much less than the motor coil DCR so the motor absorbs the heat. Then control braking by current loop to control the energy.

Comment: Are you using a GROUND PLANE? The inductive kick of 0.14 amp switching in 10 nanoseconds in 100 nanoHenry (4" of wire) is V = L  * dI/dT = 100nH * 0.14A / 10nS = 14 volts. If your local bypass capacitor (on the 0.14 amp rail) is a meter away, you'll get 140 1-4-0 volts.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf this is all breadboard. And hacked up SMD components to be breadboardable. Which definitely contributes to the issue.